# Process all lines in a file with multithreading

Tags: python

I have a big text file with lots of lines. For every line I want to do some operations and after the operation completed I want to print it into a outfile.txt.

This is what I am doing for now, but for big files it takes a lot of time.

```
with tqdm.tqdm(total=os.path.getsize(file)) as pbar:
    with open(file, encoding="utf-8") as infile:
        for line in infile:
            pbar.update(len(line))
            srline = line.replace(" ", "")
            if (
                "$HEX" not in srline
                and "@" not in srline
                and srline != "\n"
                and "BCRYPT" not in srline
                and "$2" not in srline
                and "$S$" not in srline
            ):
                outfile.write(srline)
```

Comment: Parallelizing with threads will most likely achieve nothing, since the IO is slower than the processing, and that's some really really basic processing.

You should try to split your file and then combine the results.

Comment: How big is the big file, and how much is a lot of time?

Comment: unrelated: if possible, I would split the input line and save each word into a set. Then I would check if such set intersects the set of forbidden keywords ( $HEX, BCRYPT, etc)

Comment: @LtWorf my io limit is 150MB/s and now the script takes only 20MB/s. And I prefer doing it with this method without splitting because this script has to run multiple times

Comment: @Tomalak the file il 20GB and lot of time is like 30mins. And I just noticed that if I run this script the final file is bigger than the start WTF

Comment: I don't know what `pbar.update(len(line))` does but it would likely be a time drain if it needs to update some UI to show every line's length.  Try removing it to see if makes a difference on your I/O consumption.

Comment: reading through 20 GB of text does not take 30 minutes. Your code is spending time with something other than reading lines of text. Write the simplest-possible python loop over your input file to test that premise.

Comment: I suspect tqdm might be a bit slow, so maybe try without it? You're also not showing what `outfile` is here.

Comment: Also, since you don't really need to work with strings here, you could save time by reading and writing `bytes`es.

Comment: @AlainT. that line of code updates a progressbar for seeing the progress.

Comment: @AKX outfile is basically an empty outfile.

Comment: @Just, did you try commenting out that pbar line ?  I suspect it is wasting processing time.

Comment: Yeah the progress bar is probably what the CPU is busy doing. I made this mistake when I was 16 or 17 :D

Comment: @LtWorf I tried commenting but it takes more or less the same time. Any advice to improve the code? It has to checkk all lines and if in a line there is a whitespace it has to delete the white space(spaces can be more than one so i've done the checks with a while cycle) and then write to a output file.

Comment: @JustGuardian Why isn't that "while cycle" in the code you've posted here, then..?

Comment: @LtWorf Sorry the code i posted its a newer version of the code. With the sr.replace all spaces in the lane should be replaced.